# How to get the Max Date from each month in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

How can I get the max date from each month? I don't know what is I'm doing wrong but the data is duplicating based on my results.

Here is the table.

```
history table
```

```
|ID |  from_range   |      to_range       |     price  |      main_id
1   2019-09-01 00:00:00   2019-09-15 00:00:00       5           1
2   2019-09-16 00:00:00   2019-09-30 00:00:00       10          1
3   2019-10-01 00:00:00   2019-10-15 00:00:00       15          1
4   2019-10-16 00:00:00   2019-10-19 00:00:00       20          1
5   2019-10-20 00:00:00   0000-00-00 00:00:00       25          1
```

```
current_usage table
```

```
id    main_id    total_usage   date_created
1         1          10         2019-09-01     
2         1          10         2019-09-02 
3         1          10         2019-09-03 
4         1          10         2019-09-04 
5         1          10         2019-09-05 
6         1          10         2019-09-06 
7         1          20         2019-09-07 
8         1          5          2019-09-08 
9         1          5          2019-09-09 
10        1          10         2019-09-10 
11        1          10         2019-09-15     
12        1          10         2019-09-16 
13        1          10         2019-09-17 
14        1          10         2019-09-18 
15        1          10         2019-09-19 
16        1          10         2019-09-20 
17        1          20         2019-09-25 
18        1          5          2019-09-26 
19        1          5          2019-09-27 
20        1          10         2019-09-30
21        1          10         2019-10-01 
22        1          10         2019-10-02    
23        1          10         2019-10-03 
24        1          10         2019-10-10 
25        1          10         2019-10-11 
26        1          10         2019-10-12
27        1          10         2019-10-18 
28        1          20         2019-10-20
29        1          5          2019-10-21 
30        1          5          2019-10-22
31        1          10         2019-10-23
```

so in my history_table, I got the date_range from each month, it depends if how many times the user Changes the cost for each day.

so basically

the output should be like this

```
id   price         range_date         total_usage  
1      5     2019-09-01 - 2019-09-15  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
2      10    2019-09-16 - 2019-09-30  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
3      15    2019-10-01 - 2019-10-15  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
4      20    2019-10-16 - 2019-09-19  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
5      25    2019-10-20 - 2019-10-31  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
```

AND after that I am planning to sum it all each month. based on the output of that 5 rows.

Here is my current query, I was able to do it if they only have one price history only and that is a separate query if there is only one price history, but for multiple price history I am really having a hard time to get the range from each month and their total sum.

```
SELECT price.price,
       price.from _range AS first_range, 
       price.to_range AS second_range,  
       (current_usage.total_usage),
       current_usage.date_created
FROM history AS price
INNER JOIN current_usage AS current_usage 
        ON price.main_id = current_usage .main_id
INNER JOIN(SELECT MAX(to_range) AS maxdate
           FROM history
           GROUP BY YEAR(to_range), MONTH(to_range)) x ON price.to_range= maxdate
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I really need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you simply need a join based on `date_created` of the `current_usage` table to lie [Between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) `from_range` and `to_range` of `history` table:

```sql
SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.price, 
  DATE(p.from_range) AS first_range, 
  DATE(IF(p.to_range = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', LAST_DAY(p.from_range), p.to_range)) AS second_range,
  SUM(c.total_usage) AS total_usage
FROM history AS p
INNER JOIN current_usage AS c
        ON c.main_id = p.main_id 
           AND c.date_created BETWEEN DATE(p.from_range) AND DATE(IF(p.to_range = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', LAST_DAY(p.from_range), p.to_range))
GROUP BY p.id
```

I am assuming that `id` column in the `history` table is your Primary Key. So, rest of the non-aggregated columns from `history` table in the SELECT clause are functionally dependent, and hence there is no need to specify them in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: thank you very much sir!, just one question, what if the ```p.to_range``` is 0000:00:00, the last row from each main_id will always have like that value

Comment: @JanessaBautista in this case, do you want it to be last day of that month ? You can use If to check if it is 0000-00-00 and if true, then use last_day function on from_range date.

Comment: thank you very much! I really appreciate it!. i'll just need to sum all rows to get the total!. thanks again Sir! big help!